# IIS maximum worker processes

Tags: performance, iis, networking

I've been researching this quite a bit and just wanted some professional opinions on this. I am working on an eCommerce site that is really slow for submitting orders. Would creating a web farm be beneficial? If not, what would - server, or network wise (load balancers, etc...)?

Assume the app is optimized as much as can be for now and we need to look at other alternatives.

**Environment:**

- Windows 8 RC 2
- IIS 7.5
- SQL Server 2008

**Ideas**

- IIS and database on separate server
- Load balancers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can find a cheaper solution.

If it is only the submit process which is slow perhaps you can just improve the code and use some background workers that won't block the main thread.

Otherwise what about just upgrading your server?

Answer (score 0):

1. Static file compression.
2. Create separate application pools for static and dynamic pages with in the website.
3. Get the heavy feature onto a separate app pool. Check if that helps.
4. Do optimization on SQL server end. Indexing?

Other than this I would look in to the code. IIS performance is highly dependent upon the pages being executed.

You may also want to check from browser developers tool as to which part of the request is actually clocking the most amount of time. That will give you a better idea of which aspect of performance you should really be concerned about.